# How can I fix this? My app works fine if I use expo app to emulate it on android, but it crashes when I build the apk

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo, create-react-app

I used ReactNative to create my simple app, but after I builded the apk and installed on my phone and even into others phones it didn't work. I don't know why, I made a lot of tries changing a lot of things. I don't how to fix it, I'm trying by a week. I thought the problem was that I didn't installed correctly some components but I tried making a new project without make any changes and It worked, so it is sure a problem of my project. To make my project I used expo init and then expo eject and I choiced ExpoKit, because using only expo init I doesn't have android folder and using react native I doesn't have expo, so I used this command to have both. Tells me which files you need to see. I don't know whick one put there because I don't have any more ideas of whick could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend that if you use Expo try not to eject it because it simply doesn't work well. I myself have been developing react native apps for over a year and at first I used expo for obvious simple reasons but as the app grow bigger and needed native components and api from iOS and Android the app didn't work. Some months ago I just started with react-native init and use all the frontend code from the expo before ejecting and now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. I created another project with react native, and then copy just the code without